# My time series plot showing the wrong order

Tags: python, sorting, matplotlib, plot

I'm plotting:

```
df['close'].plot(legend=True,figsize=(10,4))
```

The original data series comes in an descending order,I then did:

```
df.sort_values(['quote_date'])
```

The table now looks good and sorted in the desired manner, but the graph is still the same, showing today first and then going back in time.

Does the `.plot()` order by index? If so, how can I fix this ?
Alternatively, I'm importing the data with:

```
df = pd.read_csv(url1)
```

Can I somehow sort the data there already?

Comment: please post a sample of your data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with this code:

1) `df.sort_values(['quote_date'])` does not sort in place. This returns a sorted data frame but `df` is unchanged =>

```
df = df.sort_values(['quote_date'])
```

2) Yes, the `plot()` method plots by index by default but you can change this behavior with the keyword `use_index`

```
df['close'].plot(use_index=False, legend=True,figsize=(10,4))
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Tnx a lot!